# href does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, php

why does the following not work. it only takes me to the index.php page and cuts off the "get" data

```
 <div class="wrapper">
        <form class="form-signin" method="post">       
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Customer Not Found</h2>
              No customer was found matching <?=$_POST['phone'];?>.<br/>
              You can create a new customer with this number, or search again<br/>
              <button
                      class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"

                      id="createCust"
              >
                     Create A New Customer
              </button>   
              <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="login">Search Again</button>   
        </form>
    </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("createCust").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "index.php?proc=newCust&p=<?=$_SESSION['phone'];?>";
    };
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see any "get" data. I see `$_SESSION` data. Have you checked to see what is being generated by PHP?

Comment: The GET data is the querystring (everything after the `?`). OP is saying he's not even getting: `?proc=newCust&p=`

Comment: this is just a clip from a larger app I am writing, just doing some clean up - the folloowing `index.php?proc=newCust&p=555-555-1212 ` does not come up in the url. when the button in clicked it just goes to index.php - the rest is missing

Comment: that is correct @Scott

Comment: Note: it is a very bad idea to echo out `$_POST` data to your website with out any filtering in place, this creates instances of XSS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) you sould be using `filter_input` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) with a sanitize filter (http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

Comment: understood @cmorrissey, however that does not address the question - thanks for the tip

Comment: @Cain Just for kicks, what happens if you take out the php dynamic value from the string and just hard code the querystring?

Comment: `<?=$_SESSION['phone'];?>` -> `<?=$_POST['phone'];?>`

Comment: The default action for a button in a form is to submit the form. A pending server call will block changes to `location.href`. Define the button as type of button.

Comment: @ScottMarcus same. there is no error, it just will not url how I want it.goes right to index.php- now for "kicks" i actually did a <a href> around the button, and that works.. obviously not the way I want to do it LOL

Comment: @Teemu THANK YOU TEEMU!! that was it - and ofc it was an obvious prob LOL, always the simple stuff. -cmorrisy note: this is not a final project, it is a "storyboard" if you will, the final will have all its sanitation done.

Comment: shoot, i get a lot of my answers here - so dont usually need to ask, but how do i mark solved?

Comment: I removed "SOLVED -" from the question's title. Either post an answer and mark it as solved when it lets you or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

As @Teemu stated:

> The default action for a button in a form is to submit the form. A
>   pending server call will block changes to location.href. Define the
>   button as type of button. –

I had the "type" as submit, changing it to type="button" solved this problem.